# How can I pass an array data to Apache Wink controller using json

Tags: java, json, apache, jax-rs

I'm writing a apache wink controller which contains the following API:

```
@DELETE
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/users")
public void deleteUsers(List<String> ids) {
    // Delete users here.
    ...
}
```

I was able to pass the parameter by using **@QueryParam("ids")** annotation, but this may exceed the URL length limitation when the array is too long. Thus, I want to pass a json object to the controller and I'm wondering **1) what kind of format should the json object be** and **2) how can I receive the json object in the server side**?

P.S. I'm using Jackson in the wink side as the json parser.

Thanks in advance!

---

*I've already tried to pass the following json to wink, but it doesn't seem to work:*

```
{
   ids: ['id1', 'id2', ...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First is to create an ObjectMapper instance and then readValue() method with the value type specified in the argument. You'll get the mapped object.

For example:

```
mapper = new ObjectMapper();
idObject = mapper.readValue(jsonpayload.getBytes(), mapClass);
```

Also a valid JSON would look like this:

```
{
    "ids" : ["id1", "id2"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but I'm afraid you didn't get my meaning. I was trying to pass data from browser side to server side (apache wink), and the wink controller can accept http payload through its parameters. If I transfer an object to the server, the object will be automatically parsed to an Java object. But now, we don't have such object, so I was seeking for another solution.